# Adding common reference path in .targets/.user

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I would like to place partial path to my references in my .target/.user file. For example `MylibraryPath` some thing similar to `MSBuildToolsPath` but my own custom path.

Later I would import my .target file into my .csproj and use MylibraryPath as `$(MylibraryPath)\Reference\Win32\Release` say.

How do I define `MylibraryPath` in my target fil. Can you please create a sample target file for me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on [MsBuild properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyLibraryPath>C:\Program Files\Library\</MyLibraryPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Incidentally I had created such a target file but visual studio editor gave me errors like "The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has an invalid child element 'MyLibraryPath'. But I guess trick is to simply ignore these errors...

Comment: Yes, the automatic schema validation in VS should be ignored.